# How do I multiply a Pandas dataframe by a multiplier from a dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Starting from a dataframe like the below (simplified example of my real case):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 4.2, 5.1],
    'b': [5.0, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 4.1],
    'c': [3.9, 2.0, 4.2, 3.8, 6.7],
    'd': [3.1, 2.1, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0]
})
```

And then taking a dictionary containing some multipliers I want to multiply certain columns in the dataframe by:

```
dict = {
  "b": 0.01,
  "d": 0.001
}
```

i.e. I want to check if each column in the dataframe is in my dictionary, and if it does exist as a key, then multiply that column of the dataframe by the value in the dictionary. In this example, I would want to multiply column 'b' by 0.01 and column 'd' by 0.001. I would end up with:

```
    'a': [1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 4.2, 5.1],
    'b': [0.05, 0.042, 0.031, 0.032, 0.041],
    'c': [3.9, 2.0, 4.2, 3.8, 6.7],
    'd': [0.0031, 0.0021, 0.0012, 0.001, 0.001]
```

In my real example, the dataframe is a cleaned-up set of data read in from Excel, and the dictionary of multipliers is read in from a config file, to allow users to specify which columns need converting from whatever is in Excel to the desired/expected units of measure (e.g. converting 'g/h' in the raw data to 'kg/h' in the dataframe).

What are some good, clear ways of achieving this intent, even if I have to restructure the implementation a bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```py
df[list(dct)] *= dct.values()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     a      b    c       d
0  1.0  0.050  3.9  0.0031
1  1.1  0.042  2.0  0.0021
2  1.0  0.031  4.2  0.0012
3  4.2  0.032  3.8  0.0010
4  5.1  0.041  6.7  0.0010
```

---

If in `dct` are keys not in dataframe:

```py
tmp = {k: dct[k] for k in dct.keys() & df.columns}

df[list(tmp)] *= tmp.values()
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than my answer - use this!

Comment: @RobBaker `a *= b` is shorthand for the `a = a * b`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 4.2, 5.1],
    'b': [5.0, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 4.1],
    'c': [3.9, 2.0, 4.2, 3.8, 6.7],
    'd': [3.1, 2.1, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0]
})

dic = {
    'b': 0.01,
    'd': 0.001
}

dfKeyList = [key for key in df.keys()]

for key, value in dic.items():
    if key in dfKeyList:
        df[key] = df[key] * value

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = list(dict.keys())
vals = list(dict.values())
df[cols] = df[cols] * vals
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each element in your dataframe, then multiply when the critia is met.

```
for x in df:
    if x in dict:
        df[x] *= dict[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a new dictionary with default multiplier of all columns as 1 and update the created dictionary with your existing multiplier dictionary

```py
d = dict({col: 1 for col in df.columns},
         **{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k in df.columns})
# If you are sure keys in d exist in df.columns, use following instead
d = dict({col: 1 for col in df.columns}, **d)

out = df.mul(pd.DataFrame([d]).values, axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

     a      b    c       d
0  1.0  0.050  3.9  0.0031
1  1.1  0.042  2.0  0.0021
2  1.0  0.031  4.2  0.0012
3  4.2  0.032  3.8  0.0010
4  5.1  0.041  6.7  0.0010
```

Answer (score 0):

What is about a classic for loop?

```
for col_name, value in dct.items():
    if col_name in df.columns:
        df[col_name] *= value
```

Don't name your variables using python object names like `dict`!

Comment: This works, thanks - but the higher-rated answer is even more succinct.
Obviously my actual code does not have 'dict' as a variable name - but it seems the done thing on StackExchange is to use 'dct' for a generic dictionary, so I'll remember that for next time.